# Does 'will' as a transitive verb connote mental powers?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Since ODO positioned of the example sentence confuses me:

> 1. [formal or literary] Intend, desire, or wish (something) to happen:
>
> \1.1 1.1 [with object and infinitive] Make or try to make (someone) do something or (something) happen by the exercise of mental powers:
>
> ...With only one weekend left until Christmas, the major retailers are **willing** us all to indulge in a last-minute splurge of spending. [But the experts are already predicting that the 2002 festive period is a long way short of last year's bumper spree.](http://www.highbeam.com/doc/1P2-9992598.html)

ODO's juxtaposition of this example  sentence under 1.1, and NOT 1, confuses me. Does this sentence imply the specific mental, rather than general, desires or wishes of 'the major retailers' (eg mental marketing/psychological ploys)?  Please elucidate?

Answer (score 2):

Essentially, in this context anyway, "to will" is taking on the meaning of "to wish" or "to suggest." So yes, in a certain respect, to address your title, I might go so far as to say it has a sarcastic connotation of super powers. To me, at least, "will" in this sense is similar to a transparent persuasion. "He *wills* her to yawn by subtly fitting the word into conversation." Clearly, there's nothing supernatural there and nobody views it that way (I hope, anyway), but it's a sort of magic trick all the same.

I *think* it's actually the same sense, or at least very similar, to a will you might have to disperse your assets (your money, house, etc.) amongst heirs (children, spouse, what have you). That legal document is a way of posthumously (after death) instructing your survivors of how to share your wealth, so the same principle of persuasion (albeit less subtle) exists.

In the example you cited, the stores are *willing* customers, probably by forms of subtle advertising. For example, they might show a certain brand of makeup enough that customers are inclined to try it out, even if they don't directly relate their purchase with the ads they saw. So yes, as you say, psychological marketing ploys would fall under that.

It can also be a bit less subtle than all I've said, but that's its most common use.

---

Come to think of it, "to will something" could be viewed as synonymous with "to manipulate something into being," if that adds any clarity.

Comment: Of course, the complementary idea to the superpowers of the retailers is the idea that people are a herd of mindless shoppers.